# R: Convert all data frame rows to character vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, type-conversion, row

I have a matrix returned from the `combinations` function, something like:

```
combinations(3, 2, v=c("Yes", "No", "Maybe"))
```

Which returns a matrix with 2 columns, containing the combinations 2-by-2 of the 3 strings:

```
     [,1]    [,2] 
[1,] "Maybe" "No" 
[2,] "Maybe" "Yes"
[3,] "No"    "Yes"
```

I would like to create a data frame (or tibble), something like:

```
    values
[1] c("Maybe", "No")
[2] c("Maybe", "Yes")
[3] c("No", "Yes")
```

with just one column containing a vector with the original columns.
I need this to `sapply` a function to each row.

Is there an elegant solution? (without a `for` cycle for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` by row and convert it to `tibble` with a `list` column 'values'

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtools)
combinations(3, 2, v = c("Yes", "No", "Maybe")) %>% 
   split(seq_len(nrow(.))) %>%
   tibble(values = .)
```

---

Or another option is to create a string by `unit`ing the elements of each row

```
combinations(3, 2, v = c("Yes", "No", "Maybe")) %>% 
   as_tibble %>%
   unite(values, V1, V2, sep=", ")
```